# I'm trying to count how many times data repeats in a table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, count

I have a database that stores customer information in 2 tables.

Table stores

(`tbl.contacts`)

```
| Companyname | CountryID
```

and the second table (`tbl_geo_country`)

```
| ID | Countrycode | Name |
```

Now I want to create a report that can show me how many customers are from what country. example output

```
 | Country  | QNT |
   Norway      5
   USA         3
   Sweden      2
```

I dont know how many different countries it has stored so it also needs to check that.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to me:

```
SELECT country.Name, COUNT(contact.ID) as QNT
FROM tbl_geo_country country 
    INNER JOIN tbl.contacts contact ON country.ID = contact.CountryID
GROUP BY country.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(contact.ID)
```

Keep in mind that this would return only countries, that have at least one contact. If you also need countries that have no contacts, you need to change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: thank you very much! you solved my problem and added knowledge to to my brain :)